# jquery file uploader pathname folder

Tags: jquery, image, upload, pathname

I've been told that jQuery file uploader is the best file uploading plugin I can use, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell it to store files to a specific folder. I want the pathname to change for the file based on the contents of the page it's on. I would assume that this would be as simple as passing the ajax query some parameter, but I can't find this anywhere in the documentation. I mean, it must exist, right?

If this doesn't exist for jQuery File Uploader (!?), is there a file uploading plugin that will be cross-browser compatible, work properly, and support this feature? Honestly, jQuery File Uploader comes with a lot of bells and whistles that I don't necessarily need so I'm open to a suggestion for something simpler.

Comment: which Jquery uploader are you using?

Comment: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ this one

Comment: and what is the server side are you using?If asp.net I can help you with the full details if needed

Comment: I am writing everything in php. All I really need is a button to "opload file(s)", and put those files in a specified folder, and return their path & file names when done.

Comment: I dont know at php but If you need the details with the custom upload I can provide you.

Comment: Which details for custom upload do you mean?

Comment: Custom upload in the sense the basic plugin implementation.

Comment: Oh, I can deal with the implementation I think it's just specifically how to customize which folder to upload files to which I can't figure out.

Answer (score -1):

I specifically use http://www.plupload.com/ plugin which works fabulous and its compatible even in IE with multiple file upload and last but not the least with various fallbacks.

And my 2nd option is to go and try using http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ which is also a good one as we have good support for JQuery.